# Stored proc in .net dataset class vs studio management

Tags: asp.net

Morning all. Got myself a simple query which returns ten rows in SQL Server Management Studio. I call the stored proc by right clicking it and feeding in the parameters.

The results are returned immediately.

In .NET we have set up a dataset class, added a table adapter whose select is this same procedure. I pass in the very same parameters and the execution times out after the standard 30 seconds.  It continues to run immediately when called in sql server management studio.

Any ideas why the execution time is seemingly infinite in the .net dataset class.

The query is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetPostcodeAnalysis] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @startDate DATETIME, 
    @endDate DATETIME,
    @customerID INTEGER = NULL,
    @siteID INTEGER = -1
AS

DECLARE @itemTypeID INT
SELECT @itemTypeID=ItemTypeID FROM dbo.ItemTypes WHERE ItemTypeName = 'Advert'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

BEGIN

SET @SQL = 'SELECT  at.ActionTypeName,
            COUNT(*) AS "Count"
    FROM CustomerSites cs JOIN Items i
    ON cs.SiteID = i.SiteID
    JOIN Actions a
    ON a.ItemID = i.ItemID
    JOIN ActionTypes at 
    ON a.ActionTypeID = at.ActionTypeID
    WHERE a.DateAndTime BETWEEN @1 AND @2
    AND i.ItemTypeID = @iti
    AND at.ActionTypeName IN (''List view'', ''Full view'', ''Email enquiry'', ''Print view'', ''Directions'')'

IF @customerID IS NOT NULL
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND i.CustomerID = @c'

IF @siteID > -1
    SET @SQL = @SQL + ' AND i.SiteID = @s'


SET @SQL = @SQL + ' GROUP BY
            at.ActionTypeName
    ORDER BY 
            at.ActionTypeName'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL,
    N'@1 DATETIME, @2 DATETIME, @iti INT, @c INT, @s INT',
    @startDate, @endDate, @itemTypeID, @customerID, @siteID
```